# Java - How to get Column name on Result Set

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

Hello I'm trying to make an error when there is no matched student...
and it will display like this
`No matching records found` and I want the column name still the same but still not figuring it out... can some one tell me if this is right??

Heres my function for that... and I add comment there where I put the error... but i don't know how to get the columnname

```
public void SearchTableStudent() {
        String tempSearchValue = searchStudent.getText().trim();
        boolean empty = true;
        sql = "SELECT student_id as 'Student ID',"
                + "concat(lastname, '  ,  ', firstname, ' ', middlename) as 'Name'"
                + "FROM user "
                + "WHERE CAST(student_id as CHAR) LIKE '%" + tempSearchValue + "%'";
        try {
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                empty = false;
            }
            if(empty) {
                String error = "";
                table.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                    new Object [][] {
                        {"No matching records found",null}
                    },
                    new String [] {
     /** I WANT TO PUT THE SAME COLUMN NAME ON MY DATABASE SELECTED BUT DON't Know
 WHAT FUNCTION TO DO*/
                    }
                ));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I try like this but still gave me NULL!!! 
this code is below of `empty = false;`

```
for(int i=0; i<table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    test[i] = table.getColumnName(i);
}
```

Comment: It happens because, if there's no info from the database, you assign true to the variable empty, thus triggering the if(empty) block, which is not assigning any column names to your model. You would have to manually insert column names, but what do you want them for if the resultset is empty?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
int count = metaData.getColumnCount(); //number of column
String columnName[] = new String[count];

for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
   columnName[i-1] = metaData.getColumnLabel(i);
   System.out.println(columnName[i-1]);
}
```

Comment: hello when I try this... the result is `student_id | Name` and the expected result is `Student ID | Name` since this is the default column name

Comment: I think there's an extra closing parenthesis there - should be `columnName[i-1] = metaData.getColumnLabel(i);`

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
      ResultSetMetaData meta = resultset.getMetaData(); 

      Integer columncount = meta.getColumnCount();

      int count = 1 ; // start counting from 1 always

      String[] columnNames = new String[columncount];

      while(count<=columncount){

         columnNames [count-1] = meta.getColumnLabel(count);
         count++;

      }
```

Since here your expecting is to get the columns alias instead of column name, so you have to use ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel instead of ResultSetmetaData.getColumnName.

Comment: hello when I try this... the result is `student_id | Name` and the expected result is `Student ID | Name` since this is the default column name

Comment: There is a difference between column name and column label.So you should use the method ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel instead of ResultSetmetaData.getColumnName

Answer (score 2):

Get [`ResultSetMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) using [`ResultSet#getMetaData()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData%28%29):

```
ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
```

And then to get column name of 1st column:

```
String col1Name = meta.getColumnLabel(1);
```

Similarly to get column name of 2nd column:

```
String col2Name = meta.getColumnLabel(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the metadata

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
```

Then you can do:

```
String columnName = metaData.getColumnName(int index);
```

- [ResultSetMetaData doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnName%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

`rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(int i);`

and do not concat the query param!

Comment: then what else you suggest that combine Lastname, Firstname MI as Name

Comment: i mean `LIKE '%" + tempSearchValue + "%'` is bad, because the possible SQL injection. use preparedstatement setString method instead.

Comment: it's just school project... maybe when I finished school. I will protect my program...