# Get column name by checking specific column value MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following structure for a table name check_phone what i want to select the column name from table where specific field (company) of table is equal to 468

```
calling_nmbr ' called_nmbr'call_type'site_area'company'province'district'region 'called_ims

 779876542    ' +9370098765'   12    '    112  ' 77    ' 12     '   34   ' NULL  '  NULL   

+93799543534  ' +9378843543' missed  '  Kabul  '  98   ' London '  NULL ' 0234  '  NULL    

+93773454654 '+0379923432'  NULL    '  NULL   ' 77    ' Herat  ' NULL   ' NULL ' 233      

+93799435435 '  NULL     '  NULL    '   XY    '  98   '  NULL'  NULL '  945  'NULL
```

Note: company field has always data which is the code of company. Some company has distinct field that is not existed for other company but at least all of company has some common field so what i want to get is the name of common fields.

I want to has MySQL equivalent intersect operator between selection of first company columns name and the second company columns name.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? How do you plan to search the table if you don't know the field name?

Comment: I want to take those fields name that has data for both company

Comment: Surely you control that inside your SQL query, telling MySQL which columns you want?

Comment: if you know the result means, you should paste the result here

Comment: but the problem is this that they are not known for me and from other side allots of fields are common

Comment: calling_nmbr, called_nmbr  should be the result for me

Answer (score 0):

Column name can be accessed using metadata details from db connection. From the table i can see that there is a specific column name company from where you can get company code as other column contais different information.

If you still want to know name of the column based on content of it then get please refer this

[Java - How to get Column name on Result Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094999/java-how-to-get-column-name-on-result-set)

Comment: Yeah i can get the column name of table, but now i want to take those fields name that has value for both company

Comment: can you please write example of output you want because for me column name and field name are same

Comment: the above table schema is the brief of my table in real my table has allot of fields here i should take the name clling_nmbr, and clled_nmbr because for this two company is common or the intersect result of between company should be that two field