# Sqite select query row doesn't work

Tags: java

I use JDBC to get data from sqlite data base. In DB I have 3 column - login, password and role. I try find row by login, but it doesn't work , and I have exeption when I try `getString("password")` or `"role"`, where is the mistake? Thanks

```
resSet = statmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='"+login+"';");
if( hasUser( login)){
    System.out.println("User finded:");
    while(resSet.next()) {
        System.out.println("login = " + resSet.getString("login"));
        // !exeption   
        System.out.println("password = " + resSet.getString("password"));
        // !exeption   
        System.out.println("role = " + resSet.getString("role"));
        System.out.println();
    }
}else{
    System.out.println( "User not found");
}
```

Comment: print exception log with your question

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: no such column: 'password'
 at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.findColumn(JDBC3ResultSet.java:48)
 at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getString(JDBC3ResultSet.java:437)
 at SE_10_JDBC.task1.DataBaseHandler.readUserFromDB(DataBaseHandler.java:56)
 at SE_10_JDBC.task1.MainTask1.main(MainTask1.java:15)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: users table should have password column , the exception answers your question pretty clearly

Comment: but column password and role exsist

Comment: and that code work properly:

Comment: can you check the names of your columns with that of which you are accessing. If these are same try to run this query `select login, password, role from users WHERE login=?;`

Comment: resSet = statmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");    

        while(resSet.next()) {
            System.out.println("login = " + resSet.getString("login"));
            System.out.println("password = " + resSet.getString("password"));
            System.out.println("role = " + resSet.getString("role"));
            System.out.println();
        }

Comment: I try it, but it doesn't work too

Comment: it's probably because your query isn't returning results of password column

Comment: Please use the "edit" option under your question to put the stack trace in the question instead of the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check to see what column names are being returned.

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resSet.getMetaData();
int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

String rValue = "";
for (int i = 1; i <= colCount ; i++){

    String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
    rValue += name + " ";
}

System.out.println(rValue);
```

Comment: That means your query is wrong. or your table doesn't actually have what you think it does... or something...  what about when you "SELECT * FROM users" ?

Comment: Looks like `PRAGMA table_info([users]);` might give results similar to 'MySQL's 'describe users'  from http://stackoverflow.com/a/7679086/2801237 so that you can check your table

Comment: You are right, thanks , I found place where I done mistake. I use if(hasLogin()) wich uncorrectly

Answer (score 0):

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
int count = metaData.getColumnCount(); //number of column
String columnName[] = new String[count];

for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
  metaData.getColumnLabel(i)); 
}
```

Refer to this ans..ans see what are the names of your columns in resultant set
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094999/java-how-to-get-column-name-on-result-set](http://how%20to%20get%20column%20name)