# I'm trying to retrieve all of the column names from a database table but only "[COLUMN_NAME]" is returned?

Tags: java, mysql, database-schema

For some reason only `[COLUMN_NAME]` is returned? It is connecting to a MySQL database running on a local host.

Here is my code:

```
public static String[] getCol() throws Exception {
    try {
        Connection con = dbc.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='particles'");
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData rs =  result.getMetaData();
        int count = rs.getColumnCount();
        String[] ColName = new String[count];
        String[] COLS;
        for (int i=1 ; i <= count; i++) {
            ColName[i-1] = rs.getColumnName(i);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ColName));
        return ColName;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, the problem is in SQL. You select only `column_name`, use `select * ...` instead.

Comment: duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094999/java-how-to-get-column-name-on-result-set

Comment: definitely not a clear question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the values of `column_name` is going to be on a separate *row*. The expected return from your query will be a resultset like

```
column_name
-----------
id
name
weight
charge
flavor
spin
```

To get the actual values returned by the query, you will need to spin through the rows of the resultset, just like you would fetch rows from any other resultset you returned.

The code you are showing is only looking at the metadata of the resultsest...  names assigned to the column(s) in the `resultset`. In this case, the resultset contains a single column, with the name `column_name`. That's why you are observing the behavior you report.

If your query was written

```
 SELECT column_name AS foo
   FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE table_name='particles'
```

You'd be seeing `foo` as the column name, rather than `column_name`.

It doesn't matter one whit to SQL that the *values* in the *rows* of the resultset happen to be column names... as far as SQL is concerned, the query is returning a set of *rows*, a single column of *values*. Yes, it happens to be metadata about the columns in a table (because you are running a query against a special view named `information_schema.columns`) but the return from that query is really no different than if you ran any other query that return a VARCHAR column from any other table. For example:

```
SELECT mystringcol FROM mytable
```

If you used that query in your code, the metadata for the resultset would be a single column, with a name `mystringcol`. And your code wouldn't be doing anything with the *rows* returned in the resultset, the actual values of mystringcol.